# Login/Logout process for ROR (Rails 3.2.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are new to ROR, We have issue in creating Login/Logout process in ROR (Rails 3.2.2/ruby 1.9.3p125). Can you please provide some details steps to do below,

1. How to code for Login/Logout process
2. How to change the table as well as fields as per my requirement for
   it.
3. How to customize signup and change the table and fields.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards,
Chirag Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend to use gem called **sorcery** for such problems. it's really awesome one, i use it in every my project, Visit [tutorial](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Simple-Password-Authentication)

Benefits:

- No built-in or generated code
- Configuration over Confusion
- Keep MVC cleanly separated

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have impliment it but I got the below error in the registration 
"      
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name "

Comment: I have define the "firstname" in attr_accessible. So above error is resolved and got the this error "undefined method `salt=' for #<User:0x9255f90>". Can you please guide me.

Comment: In Login, I got this error "undefined method `authenticate' for Object:Class"

Comment: as i know there's no authenticate method in login session, really strange

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  attr_accessible :firstname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 3, :message => "password must be at least 3 characters long", :if => :password
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :message => "should match confirmation", :if => :password
end

Comment: For Login ; I got this error Started POST "/user_sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-27 19:15:53 +0530
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4eS0yQrw5wajZEzsDicaVveaT72/KLcF7D1Uw18f3VI=", "email"=>"asd@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate' for Object:Class):
  app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:9:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Comment: have you got the issue? I have attached sql file also in that.

Comment: heyy, you even didn't install Sorcery!! i've completed this application, i've forked you app, and completed: you can clone: git@github.com:Saidbek/project_tracking.git

Comment: Kaidybaev Thanks for your help and quick response. Application is working. Can you please guide me, which place you found the issue in my code.

Comment: Hello Said, If I am using with sqllite then project is working fine But When I used with mysql then I got the error "undefined method `salt' for #<User:0xad3fcac>".

Comment: this error means that column salt is not defined in your migration

Comment: to get rid of this error, configure your config/database.yml to use mysql, then replace gem 'sqlite3' from Gemfile to gem 'mysql2' and run bundle, then rake db:create && rake db:migrate

Comment: I have already define the "mysql2" in Gemfiles and configure config/database.yml. I have not used salt/crypted_password in  code. For testing, I have added salt as well as crypted_password fields then If I am adding any value in password field then this value consider for crypted_password field, not for the password field for user table so I have remove the password field from the database then New user scripts is running but login is not working with same detail.

Comment: This give the error "Email or password was invalid". Can you please provide the solution for the same and From which place salt and crypted_password automatically is add in the table because I have not using this field in the code.

Comment: pull changes, i've converted app to use mysql, see, don't use crypted_password or salt, nowhere, read smth about salt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: I have pull the latest code and test on my local server and updated github link. I got the same error ""undefined method `salt' for" . If I am adding this field then same issue happen for login. Thanks for your help but I am Freshers for ROR so I am not able to solve easily. Can you please check and give the idea for the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Register and login is working perfect. Can you please explain me why I required to salt and crypted_password fields? why password value is consider for crypted_password? What you have changed for solve the login error? what you have done in code for solve the 'authenticate' error? why we need to create helper file for all controller? which gem or code will use for validation of login and register?

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to chat with Said Kaldybaev about the same?

Answer (score 3):

Please read about [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Or http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1